# Functions applications

Tags: python, python-3.x

**PROGRAM QUESTION**:Write a python code to check for sum equivalent numbers ?

Two numbers are said to be sum equivalent if they have same number of digits and sum of their digits are equal.

**My code**:

```
n=int(input())
l={}
g=[]
for i in range(n):
    t=0
    x=int(input())
    q=str(x)
    for f in range(len(q)):
        t=t+int(q[f])
    l[x]=t
w=list((l.keys()))
p=list(str(i) for i in w)
for k in range(1,len(p)):
    if len(p[0])==len(p[k]):
        if l[w[0]]==l[w[k]]:
            g.append(str(w[k]))
        else:
            continue
print(p[0])        
if len(g)>0:
    for num in range(len(g)):
        print(g[num])
else:
    print('none are sum equivalent')
```

**My question**:Can anyone modify this code using functions or suggest a new code using functions ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be an example of using functions; I have made some re-factors:

```
def find_sum_equivalent_numbers(n):
    l = dict()
    g = list()
    for i in range(n):
        t = 0
        x = int(input())
        q = str(x)
        for f in range(len(q)):
            t += int(q[f])
        l[x] = t
    w = list((l.keys()))
    p = list(str(i) for i in w)
    for k in range(1, len(p)):
        if len(p[0]) == len(p[k]):
            if l[w[0]] == l[w[k]]:
                g.append(str(w[k]))
            else:
                continue
    return g


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = int(input())
    sq_list = find_sum_equivalent_numbers(n=number)
    print('\n'.join([str(sq_list[num]) for num in sq_list]) if len(sq_list) 
          else 'none are sum equivalent')
```